# Advanced Mobile View

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I use Bootstrap for responsiveness. But my client likes the mobile view of https://www.konga.com

How is this achieved, or what kinda framework is used for this, or is it an app embedded into the website?

Comment: You have to hide some properties for mobile view with hidden-lg hidden-md class. You can contact with me. I will help you details. skype: nafeeur.rahman1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved by using bootstrap grid layout with custom styling. There cannot be a framework for such requirements. Bootstrap framework provides the initial base for developing UI elements, rest can be easily customized using Normal CSS styles that depends on designer